# How do I disable Chrome extensions in PWAs only?

Tags: google-chrome, extension

I installed several PWAs from Google Chrome (83) on MacOS. The general experience is great, however I'd prefer not to use some chrome extensions in PWAs. I tried to disable unwanted extensions from the PWA window, but the they are disabled in the browser too.

Is there any way I can disable some chrome extensions in PWA only?

Comment: Just as a note, this question has been asked in the public google forums here:   https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/74412328?hl=en , but with no answer unfortunately there too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To disable specific Chrome extensions in PWAs only, you can create a separate profile in Google Chrome dedicated to your PWAs. Here's how you can do it:

1. Open Google Chrome on your MacOS.
2. Click on "Profiles" from the menu
   bar at the top-right corner.
3. Click "Add" to create a new profile.
4. In the opened window, select "Continue without an account" to create a
   profile without linking it to any Google account. This is important
   because linking an account might sync the extension settings across
   profiles.
5. Once you've set up the new profile, open the website of
   the PWA you want to install.
6. Install the PWA app using the dedicated profile.

By doing this, the extensions you have installed in your
primary Chrome profile won't be automatically carried over to the
new profile with the PWA. This way, you can manage your extensions
separately, enabling or disabling them only for the PWA profile
without affecting the extensions in your main Chrome profile.

Now, if you install PWAs using this new profile, the extensions you enable or disable in this profile will only affect the PWAs and not your main Chrome browser. This allows you to customize the extension usage according to your preferences within the PWAs.